# Суффиксный массив. Нахождение наименьшего циклического сдвига строки

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

У меня есть какая-то строка и я строю ее суффиксный массив

Всегда ли первый элемент суффиксного массива совпадает с позицией наименьшего циклического сдвига строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, всё верно, первый элемент указывает на позицию наименьшего циклического сдвига.

Один из методов построения СМ как раз сортирует циклические сдвиги строки (со вставкой спецсимвола)

см. "применения" [здесь](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/suffix_array#3)